# How are process id PID assigned on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, process

I see the pricessid ranging from 800 to arround 6500. So what process or algorithm does Ubuntu use to assign unique pid to the process?

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://superuser.com/questions/135007/how-are-pids-generated), and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid).

Answer (score 1):

The `kernel` beneath the ubuntu platfrom uses some `process-scheduling algorithm` to schedule the process by accessing its `PCB` (Process Control Block).
PCB is a `datastructure` in `linux` OS where the whole information is kept regarding the `process` and the `processID` is also kept in that data structure. You can also see the PCB in linux under `/proc/`